# Open Microsoft Word docx file with Java

Tags: java, file, io, docx

How can I open a Microsoft Word docx file in Java? furthermore, how can I open it if it is password protected?

For instance,

```
File f = new File("hello.docx");
```

Please try to avoid responding with things such as "you shouldn't do this." I have a good reason for this, so please stick to the question when you answer. thanks a lot!

Comment: Use POI (http://poi.apache.org) or docx4j (http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j/)

Comment: can you show an example with reading docx with password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) project for working with MS Office files. DOCX file is just a zip file with series of XML files inside, so you can unzip the file and work with XML. The XML spec (Open XML) is known.

Comment: Sadly Apache POI doesn't handle tables, headers, or Images very easily.  Docx4J is a little more robust.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't personally used it, but it looks like Apache POI will work for you: http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: I would also Recommend POI. If you want to read/write the file, then its the best Apache License 2.0 library available(or to which I came across)

Comment: Can you show example code for reading word doc with password?

Comment: @CodeGuy I'm not going to do that research for you. I simply google'd your question and found this project. As I stated above, I have not used it personally.

Answer (score 3):

You can use docx4j too. http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Comment: You can read the http://www.docx4java.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/docs/Docx4j_GettingStarted.html.

You can find alot of examples there.

Comment: With docx4j 2.8.0 snapshot, it is just OpcPackage.load(new java.io.File("some.docx"), "password123")

Answer (score 2):

I have used both docx4j and Apache's POI libraries, if you are working with .docx I would recommend .docx4j.  Automated alot of the process of creating a .docx.
There is a great exmaple here : http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-complex-word-docx 
on how to create a .docx using the docx4j package.

Answer (score 1):

If the docx is password protected, it won't be a zip file. It will be a compound file. See [Overview of Protected Office Open XML Documents](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/openspecification/archive/2009/07/17/overview-of-protected-office-open-xml-documents.aspx)

To read a compound file in Java, use [POIFS](http://poi.apache.org/poifs/index.html).  POIFS is part of POI (docx4j uses it as well, so if you download the docx4j distribution, you'll be able to use the POIFS API)

Once you have decrypted the encrypted package, you can read it using docx4j or POI.

Edit: OK, now docx4j can [handle password-protected docx](http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j/changeset/1808) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to open it using the [Open Office api](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OpenOffice.org_Developers_Guide)? It can work with a lot of documents types.

I used it with MS Excel files .xls ( old version ) format.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Can you show example code of how you opened MS with password?